# Someone's answer is completely copied and pasted from my answer, and their answer got accepted.

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Someone's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809480/398708) to a question is completely copied and pasted from my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809405/398708) (except they didn't use Mathjax), and their answer got accepted. I don't mind, but I just think it's strange behavior, for both the copier and the asker.

What do you think is going on here, and should I do anything about this?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. Done.

Comment: "completely copied and pasted from my answer (except they didn't use Mathjax)" not using Mathjax, that's highly commendable, and shows effort.

Comment: I have had a look : it is astonishing ! How is it possible to (ill) copy textually an answer ???

Comment: @JeanMarie Just by cutting and pasting from one answer to the other I can get almost exactly the same effect except that the letters come out in a Roman font instead of italics and I have to delete a few stray linefeeds. My guess is that this user's computer allows them to capture the font as well.

Comment: Relevant question on Meta StackOverflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268629/2805120

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you must raise a flag in these situations, and the moderator team will handle it.